# Resize an existing Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I created a GUI in netbeans using absolute layout for most of it. I want my components to auto resize and I know you have to use gridbag layout to do so. Will I have to restart using gridbag from the beginning or is it possible to change the existing code and leave all the components in the same place.

I tried changing my components to all be gridbag layout but it only opens a very small window. When i expand it its just a blank grey screen.

Comment: *"I know you have to use gridbag layout to do so"* -- no, this is incorrect. There isn't one single layout that is required or that must be used, but rather multiple layout managers that may be used, in combination or alone, all depending on the exact requirements. Myself, I would recommend ***not*** using GridBagLayout unless you have no other alternatives.

Comment: *"but it only opens a very small window"* -- meaning you likely forgot to set the weightx and weighty to non-zero values of the relevant GridBagConstraints.

Comment: But your question really needs much more focus and detail to be adequately answered without writing a tutorial or giving very broad advice (such as given above).

Comment: Always mention your Java GUI framework when posting here: Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, Android, etc. I assumed you meant Swing, and added a mention and tag for you.

Comment: I think we’ve established the “basic” answer to your question - make use of appropriate layout managers

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid absolute positioning

You said:

> I created a GUI in netbeans using absolute layout for most of it.

Rarely a good idea, for the reasons you have encountered: Such a layout is inflexible, forces the programmer to do the pixel math, and takes away the user's ability to re-size.

The layout managers in Swing were invented to more easily give resizing flexibility to the user, and to automatically accommodate variations in rendering size across platforms.

## Keep nearly all your code when adding a layout manager

You said:

> Will I have to restart … from the beginning

No. You are not starting from scratch. You already figured what widgets are needed, and their general arrangement. You already wrote behavior for those widgets. You already wrote business logic behind the scenes to support those widgets’s behavior. All that code you keep.

All you need to do is:

- Decide on an appropriate layout manager, or multiple layout managers the be nested within one another.
- Add your already-defined widgets to those layout manager(s).

## `GridBagLayout` is only one of several layout managers

You said:

> I want my components to auto resize and I know you have to use gridbag layout to do so.

No, not necessarily [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). Swing offers a variety of bundled layout managers. All of them provide for auto resizing.

In addition, you may choose to add any of several third-party layout managers.

Choose one, or more, to suit your needs.

Oracle provides at no cost a wide-ranging [tutorial on Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). I suggest you study that. Note the [visual example of several layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). These include:

- BorderLayout
- BoxLayout
- CardLayout
- FlowLayout
- GridBagLayout
- GridLayout
- GroupLayout
- SpringLayout

The most surprisingly useful is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). This layout manager accommodates elements commonly seen in run-of-the-mill business apps. The top `NORTH` can hold menus, subtitles, Help button, and such. The left `WEST` might hold a navigation bar. The right `EAST` might have a status panel, or descriptive help content. The bottom `SOUTH` can have [breadcrumbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_navigation), *Accept* & *Cancel* buttons, etc. Your business form goes into the center. Any unused empty side collapses, to not waste any space.

You will need to practice. Each layout manager has its own logic and its own quirks. You will need to get to know and love each on its own merits. Have patience; the time spent up front learning the layout managers is more than repaid by time spent later futzing with rearranging forms to accommodate changes.

In particular, I suggest you start very simply with `FlowLayout`.

Keep in mind the concept of nesting one layout manager inside another. After you get familiar with the various layout managers, sketch your desired form on paper. In that sketch, look for groups of widgets that can be gathered into a sub-layout. Then look to a those sub-layouts being arranged in an outer layout such as `BorderLayout`.

## Specify constraints with `GridBagLayout` to fix window size

You said:

> my components to all be gridbag layout but it only opens a very small window. When i expand it it's just a blank grey screen.

Regarding window size, with `GridBagLayout` you need to set [constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html). Here is some example code, my abbreviation of [example code provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java) to demonstrate `GridBagLayout`.

```java
package work.basil.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

// An abbreviated version of example code provided by Oracle from:
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java
public class HelloWorldSwing
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated( true );

        // Establish the window, represented by a `JFrame` object.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "My First Hello World App" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        makeContent( frame.getContentPane() );

        // Show window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    private static void makeContent ( Container container )
    {
        container.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton button1 = new JButton( "Button 1" );
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  // Natural height. Maximum width.
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        container.add( button1 , c );

        JButton button2 = new JButton( "Button 2" );
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        container.add( button2 , c );

        JButton buttonLongName = new JButton( "Long-Named Button 4" );
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 40;      // Make this component tall.
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        container.add( buttonLongName , c );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Assign a task to event-dispatching thread: Create and show our GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( HelloWorldSwing :: createAndShowGUI );
    }
}
```

When run:

[image: screenshot of example Swing app using GridBagLayout with minimal usable window size]

`GridBagLayout` is the most powerful, most flexible layout manager bundled with Java. But `GridBagLayout` is also the most complicated, and the most difficult to learn. As mentioned above, I strongly recommend using other layout managers when first learning Swing.

## *JavaFX*

By the way, if just starting out with Swing, be aware that Swing is now in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) is bundled with every version of Java, and will be fully supported for many more years. But know that Oracle has declared [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) to be the official successor to Swing.

You may want to choose to invest your learning time in JavaFX rather than Swing. But if you are in a hurry with a relatively simple app, then just add a Swing layout manager, and be done.

See:

- Oracle post: [*Java Client Roadmap Updates*](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/java-client-roadmap-updates) (2020-05)
- Oracle white paper: [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) (2020-05)